# AttributeError? How to split a decision tree into 10 columns with 2 values each?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am creating a decision tree with 19 columns with 2 values each and while I am splitting the tree and I get an Attribute Error.

Error states:

groups = clf.groupby('column1')
AttributeError: 'DecisionTreeClassifier' object has no attribute 'groupby'

```
import pandas as PD
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, accuracy_score



data_set= PD.read_csv('hw6.data.csv.gz')

x= data_set.iloc[:, :10].values
y= data_set.iloc[:, 10]


x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(x,y, test_size=.2, random_state=42)


clf =DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
split_values = clf.tree_.threshold
impurity = clf.tree_.impurity

print(data_set)

groups = clf.groupby('column1')

def split_group(group): 
    subgroup1= group[group['column2'] =='value1']
    subgroup2= group[group['column2'] =='value2']
    return [subgroup1, subgroup2]

split_data = groups.apply(split_group)

print(split_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

clf is not a dataframe but a decision tree instance. So change the code as follows:

before

```
groups = clf.groupby('column1')
```

after

```
groups = data_set.groupby('column1')
```